# Decidability of languages with dfa/turing-machines

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, semi-decidability

For any alphabet and any natural number k, a language of strings at least k is decidable.

So my question is having some alphabet (let's say (0,1)) and some number let's say k=5 then my language has every string of 1's and 0's that are 5 or more characters at length (ie 01101, 011011 belong to language, while 011,10,1100 does not). Can such language be decidable and how so?

Answer (score 1):

The easy and immediate way to see this is to note that the language of strings of length at most $k$ is finite, therefore it is regular. Regular languages are closed under complementation (just switch the accept and reject states), so your language of strings of length greater than $k$ is also regular.